# Custom permissions on Django group form

Tags: python, django

I've added some custom permissions to my Post model.

I've also created a form to add/edit groups with only this custom permissions:

```
class GroupFornm(forms.ModelForm):
    permissions = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=Post._meta.permissions)

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = '__all__'
```

It works because I can see and select only my custom permissions but when I try to save the form I got the error:

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'can_view'

What am I doing wrong? It seems that this form field waits for (int, str) pair but documentation says that as usually, (str, str) should work.

**Edit**

Post._meta.permissions:

`(('can_view', 'Can see tickets'), ('can_edit', 'Can edit tickets'), ('can_delete', 'Can delete tickets'), ('can_create', 'Can add new tickets'))`

Comment: Can you share the `Post._meta.permissions`?

Comment: Yes, I edit the question adding this

Comment: Hmm. I think it is not the field itself that results in problems, but probably the fact that these permissions are later *translated* into `Permission` fields.

Comment: So maybe I need to overwrite form save method in order to first create permissions and then add to group?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not really related to the form itself, but the fact that you somehow need to translate those `permissions` into `Permission` objects that should be stored in the `Group` instance (the one that this `ModelForm` is managing).

I think displaying the options is not a problem. But if a user later for example performs a `POST` request, with the options (like `can_write`), then the question is how the `Form` should translate these into `Permission` objects (or the primary keys of `Permission` objects).

In that case you need to *coerce* the name of the permissions to `Permission` objects, or the `id`s of `Permission` objects. We can for example use a `TypedMultipleChoiceField`, and coerce with:

```
def get_permission_from_name(name):
    return Permission.objects.get(name=name)

class GroupFornm(forms.ModelForm):
    permissions = forms.TypedMultipleChoiceField(
        choices=Post._meta.permissions,
        coerce=get_permission_from_name,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = '__all__'
```

Note that the above is not really a very efficient implementation, since it requires a query for *every* value send. Furthermore in case no permission with that name exists, then this will raise an error.

If you want to construct `Permission`s on the fly (in case these are not yet constructed), then you can change the function to:

```
def get_permission_from_name(name):
    return Permission.objects.get_or_create(
        name=name,
        defaults={
            'content_type': ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Post),
            'codename': name
        }
    )
```

Comment: Okay, it seems good but now I get an error saying that no Permission matching query. Is because my custom permissions have only been declared in Post model? So, I also need to create them as Permission object in some point :S

Comment: @P.Rodoreda: not per se, we could change the `.get(..)` to `.get_or_create(..)`, so to make permissions on the fly. But this can of course is a bit unsafe, since a hacker could alter the `POST` data, and hope to create permissions on the fly as well.

Comment: @P.Rodoreda: so I indeed advice you to create the permissions. You can however programmatically scan the `._meta`s and create those permissions.

Comment: I'm doing something wrong for sure. Now, I get: NOT NULL constraint failed: auth_permission.content_type_id